# junit test case for spring-integration-file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp, springjunit4classrunner, spring-integration-aws

Am newbie to Spring. I have a spring project created using spring-integration-file (spring boot- FTP,SFTP,NFS) which will transform the file from source path to destination path.

Have to write junit test cases to test the project. It will be helpful if someone share some documents/link to write junit testcases with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) for spring-integration-file project

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consult Spring Integration Samples [project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/applications/file-split-ftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/filesplit/ApplicationTests.java) on the matter.

Also there are a lot of JUnit tests in the `spring-integration-file` module of the core [project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-file/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/file) per se.